# Error accessing project resource from Silverlight Test project

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, resources

I am doing unit tests for Silverlight 4 in Visual Studio 2010.

The problem is I am not able to use resources added to test project.

During test run when I try to access a resouce like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class Class1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // here I have an exception
        Debug.WriteLine(Properties.Resources.String1);
```

, I get an exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load type "System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute" from assembly "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

Stack trace is

```
System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethod(Int32 methodToken, RuntimeTypeHandle* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, RuntimeTypeHandle* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandle(Int32 methodToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData..ctor(Module scope, CustomAttributeRecord caRecord)
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(Module module, Int32 tkTarget)
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly target)
System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetNeutralResourcesLanguage(Assembly a, UltimateResourceFallbackLocation& fallbackLocation)
System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
SilverlightClassLibraryTestProject1.Properties.Resources.get_String1() in D:\Work\Temp\SilverlightClassLibraryTestProject1\SilverlightClassLibraryTestProject1\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs: line 68
SilverlightClassLibraryTestProject1.Class1.Test1() in D:\Work\Temp\SilverlightClassLibraryTestProject1\SilverlightClassLibraryTestProject1\Class1.cs: line 13
```

What I can see, a Silverlight test project created by Visual Studio contains a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework which is a .net Framework 4.0 assembly, not a Silverlight one.

My question is: is it possible to use resources in Silverlight Test projects with the help of ResourceManager now? If yes, then what should be done?

Here is a sample [test project](http://taera.ru/SilverlightClassLibraryTestProject1.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create a Silverlight Test project I do not have that reference.  Also, Silverlight projects do not have a Resources tab in the project properties, which it looks like your project does (a full .NET project puts the project resources under Properties.Resources namespace).

The zip provided is corrupted so I could not look at the project directly, though I'm fairly certain that the test project you created is a Full .NET test project instead of a Silverlight Test project.  You'll need to make sure to use a Silverlight Test Project.  You can then add a Resource file via Add New Item -> General -> Resources File.

Edit:

Your project is referecing a full .NET framework testing DLL:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

You need to reference:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Testing\Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Testing\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight.dll
```

Note that those DLL's are found in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).  Also, it looks like you created a Silverlight Class Library - the template you should be using is called "Silverlight Unit Test Application".  This is because Silverlight tests currently require you to run them in-browser and so they need an "Application" class.  You can use the normal Silverlight Application template, though you'd have to reference those previously mentioned testing DLL's and make the following alteration in the application code behind:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
}
```

Comment: I have re-uploaded a test project to other location.

Comment: I am creating a Silverlight Class Library Test Project and I have Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework assembly referenced.
It has TestClassAttribute and TestMethodAttribute in it. If you do not have Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework in your Silverlight Test projects, then I suppose you are not able to use [TestClass] etc.

Comment: And please note that I had added a resource file to project and the problem is I am not able to use that added resource during test run

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I had used the online template named "Silverlight Unit Test Application". And it adds a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll.
I have uninstalled Visual Studio, Silverlight tools etc and have installed them back. And to my surprise the test is working now with a (default) refernce to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll.